# Adding a Collection of Interfaces to an Interface

Tags: c#, interface, icollection

I'm trying to wrap my head around interfaces. I keep stumbling on implimenting something like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    ICollection<IBar> Bars { get; set; }
    //some other properties
}
public interface IBar
{
    //some properties
}
//assume Bar is implemented and extends IBar. Some instaces of Bar are created
Bar[] MyBars = {bar1, bar2};
Foo MyFoo = new Foo();
MyFoo.Bars=MyBars.ToList(); //This causes an error saying Collection<Bar> cannot be
//assigned to ICollection<IBar>.
```

I'm completely at a loss on how to do this properly. What is the proper way to populate a collection of interfaces?

edit: The way I've implemented Foo is probably part of the problem.

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public ICollection<IBar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to use Collection<T> instead of ICollection<T>?

Comment: @Fuex The foo class is probably part of the problem. One moment.

Comment: You are trying the put a collection of `Bar` inside a collection of `IBar`. Interfaces cannot be assumed implicitly convertable by the compiler.

Comment: I took his comment:
//assume Foo and Bar are implemented and extend IFoo and IBar, and some instaces 
//of Bar are created
... to indicate he knew that already and has done that.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion below?

Comment: I'm currently adjusting my code. I had previously set my ICollection<Bar> instead of ICollection<IBar> to get my code working. Now that I've switched it back there are a few errors I need to clear.

Comment: I have attached the whole source example to my answer. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Foo` class which should be:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

---

Or if you want to use `ICollection<IBar>`:

```
IBar[] MyBars = { bar1, bar2 };
Foo MyFoo = new Foo( );
MyFoo.Bars = MyBars.ToList( );
```

Or the more elegant solution:

```
Bar[] MyBars = { bar1, bar2 };
Foo MyFoo = new Foo( );
MyFoo.Bars = MyBars.ToList<IBar>( ); //Cast from Bar to IBar
```

Infact the problem happened because you could't convert `ICollection<Bar>` to `ICollection<IBar>`.

Comment: Just a note for anyone coming by this later: Foo cannot have a property named Bars that is of a different type than IFoo's property named Bars.

Answer (score 1):

For your way, you can do it like so:

```
ICollection<Bar> MyBars = new Bar[] {bar1, bar2};
MyFoo.Bars = MyBars;
```

You can also do it this way, which, programmatically might be better for you:

```
List<Bar> lstBar = new List<Bar>();
lstBar.Add(bar1);
lstBar.Add(bar2);
MyFoo.Bars = lstBar;
```

The whole source:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    ICollection<IBar> Bars { get; set; }
}
public interface IBar
{

}
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public ICollection<IBar> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class Bar : IBar
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFoo myFoo = new Foo();
        List<IBar> lstBar = new List<IBar>();
        lstBar.Add(new Bar());
        myFoo.Bars = lstBar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How you have implemented the Bars property matters here. You cannot assign a concrete type to an interface type. When you try to do the ToList conversion, you are converting it to concrete list type and trying to assign it to ICollection interface type, hence it is generating error.

The following should work fine.

```
public class Foo:IFoo
{
    public ICollection<IBar> Bars { get; set; }
}

Bar bar1 = new Bar();
Bar bar2 = new Bar();
Bar[] MyBars = { bar1, bar2 };
Foo MyFoo = new Foo();
MyFoo.Bars = MyBars;
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work this way. See, `ICollection<T>` is not covariant on `T`, therefore an `ICollection<Bar>` is not an `ICollection<IBar>` even though `Bar` is an `IBar`.

Why is it so? Imagine that there is some `Quux` implementing `IBar`. If you could assign `ICollection<Bar>` to `ICollection<IBar>`, someone could insert a `Quux` into the collection using `ICollection<IBar>.Add`, because `Quux` is an `IBar`, too! But the collection is a collection of `Bar`s, so the type safety would be broken.

You should try

```
IBar[] MyBars = {bar1, bar2};
```

This way your `MyBars` allows insertion of other `IBar`s, not only `Bar`s.